# Drawing a right triangle

Tags: java

I'm new to java and need some help with the program:

This program will output a right triangle based on user specified height triangleHeight and symbol triangleChar.

(1) The given program outputs a fixed-height triangle using a * character. Modify the given program to output a right triangle that instead uses the user-specified triangleChar character. (1 pt)

(2) Modify the program to use a nested loop to output a right triangle of height triangleHeight. The first line will have one user-specified character, such as % or *. Each subsequent line will have one additional user-specified character until the number in the triangle's base reaches triangleHeight. Output a space after each user-specified character, including after the line's last user-specified character. (2 pts)

Example output for triangleChar = % and triangleHeight = 5:

```
Enter a character:
%
Enter triangle height:
5

% 
% % 
% % % 
% % % % 
% % % % %
```

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawRightTriangle {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      char triangleChar;
      int triangleHeight;

      System.out.println("Enter a character:");
      triangleChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);   

      System.out.println("Enter triangle height:");
      triangleHeight = scnr.nextInt();
      System.out.println("");

      System.out.println("*" + " ");
      System.out.println("*" + " " + "*" + " ");
      System.out.println("*" + " " + "*" + " " + "*" + " ");
   }
}
```

Comment: What kind of help? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page: SO isn't really a CWaaS site, you need to be specific with regards to what's happening, what's *supposed* to be happening, what steps have been taken to fix or diagnose, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    char triangleChar;
    int triangleHeight;

    System.out.println("Enter a character:");
    triangleChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println("Enter triangle height:");
    triangleHeight = scnr.nextInt();

    int counter = 1;//Counts the number of chars for each line
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleHeight; i++) {
        String currentLine = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
            currentLine += triangleChar + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(currentLine);
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!
Added 
   System.out.println("");
 after triangleHeight = scnr.nextInt();{
that worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawRightTriangle {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        char triangleChar;
        int triangleHeight;

        System.out.println("Enter a character:");
        triangleChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Enter triangle height:");
        triangleHeight = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 1; i <= triangleHeight; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(triangleChar + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a character:
%
Enter triangle height:
5

% 
% % 
% % % 
% % % % 
% % % % %
```